# How to use Windows netsh firewall command to allow only specific ipaddress on all port and deny all other ipaddress?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall, netsh

I require a configuration of firewall which will allow me connection through only specific ip-address say 10.0.0.1 on all port ranging from 0-5555 and deny all other ip-addresses?

What will be the syntax of netsh firewall command to generate this type of rule on Windows 2008R2 machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands:

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Trusted In" dir=in action=allow protocol=ANY remoteip=62.9.97.12`

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Trusted Out" dir=out action=allow protocol=ANY remoteip=62.9.97.12`

Comment: could you give a bit of context/explanation to your answer? [Good answers](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) tend to include an answer to the question itself, as well as practical examples.

Comment: this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
    netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="my rule" new remoteip=157.60.0.67
```